# Splitting large file per number of CRLF row delimiters

Tags: powershell

I have a file that is over 1.5GB, I am looking to split it into smaller chunks to do some work and re-append after.

I have the below script which splits per x number of lines. The file can contain lines which are a mixture of CRLF and LF only delimiters.

What I would be looking for would be to split per x number of CRLF row delimiters, because in the existing script I could split two complete data entries. CRLF is the defining delimiter between records, the LFs exist in free text fields.

**Note:** The below code also turns existing LF into CRLF. I'd be looking to maintain the row delimiters as per the original.

Version is 5.1

```
$sourceFolder_local="D:\FileCleaning\"
$raw = $sourceFolder_local + $file.name

#split test
$sw = new-object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
$sw.Start()
$filename = $raw
$rootName = $raw.Replace(".csv","")
$ext = ".csv"

$linesperFile = 100000
$filecount = 1
$reader = $null
try{
    $reader = [io.file]::OpenText($filename)
    try{
        "Creating file number $filecount"
        $writer = [io.file]::CreateText("{0}{1}.{2}" -f ($rootName,$filecount.ToString("000"),$ext))
        $filecount++
        $linecount = 0

        while($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true) {
            "Reading $linesperFile"
            while( ($linecount -lt $linesperFile) -and ($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true)){
                $writer.WriteLine($reader.ReadLine());
                $linecount++
            }

            if($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true) {
                "Closing file"
                $writer.Dispose();

                "Creating file number $filecount"
                $writer = [io.file]::CreateText("{0}{1}.{2}" -f ($rootName,$filecount.ToString("000"),$ext))
                $filecount++
                $linecount = 0
            }
        }
    } finally {
        $writer.Dispose();
    }
} finally {
    $reader.Dispose();
}
$sw.Stop()

Write-Host "Split complete in " $sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds "seconds"
```

Comment: The data example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SJV7TH8qW_2g0g4Ji1FuStsyUpYAedy6/view?usp=sharing  (from the comments in the answer from @f6a4) doesn't include any `LF` that is *not* preceded with an `CR`. Can you provide an example for testing that includes both the isolated `LF` and `CRLF` as described in your question? Please add this (link) to the question.

Comment: @iRon reuploaded, same link should hopefully work and there should be an LF only on row 5.

Answer (score 1):

This script splits the file by a string delimiter you choose (e.g. CRLF):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Collections

$file          = get-item 'D:\test\largefile.txt'
$delimiter     = [environment]::NewLine      # delimiter to split file
$delimCounter  = 5                           # split after X occurances of delimiter


$fileReader   = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new( $file, [System.Text.Encoding]::default,$true)
$peek         = $fileReader.Peek()
$encoding     = $fileReader.CurrentEncoding
[void]$fileReader.Close()
[void]$fileReader.Dispose()

switch( $encoding.BodyName ) {
    'utf-8' {
        $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
        break
    }
    'utf-7' {
        $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF7
        break
    }
    'utf-16' {
        $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode
        break
    }
    'utf-32' {
        $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF32
        break
    }
    'bigendianunicode' {
        $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::BigEndianUnicode
        break
    }
    'ascii' {
        $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
        break
    }
    default {
        $enc = $null
    }
}

if( $enc ) {
    $delimiter = [string]::new( $enc.GetBytes($delimiter) )
}

$fileReader    = [System.IO.FileStream]::new( $file, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open )
$delimBuffer   = [System.Collections.Generic.List[byte]]::new()
$fileBuffer    = [System.Collections.Generic.List[byte]]::new()
$fileCounter   = 0
$delimCounter1 = $delimCounter

[void]$delimBuffer.AddRange( [byte[]]0 * $delimiter.Length )

$byte = $fileReader.ReadByte()

while( $byte -ge 0 ) {

    [void]$delimBuffer.RemoveAt(0)
    [void]$delimBuffer.Add( [byte]$byte )
    [void]$fileBuffer.Add( [byte]$byte )

    if( [String]::new( $delimBuffer ) -eq $delimiter ) {
        $delimCounter1--
        if( !$delimCounter1 ) {
            # remove last CRLF (if not needed, remove next line)
            [void]$fileBuffer.RemoveRange( $fileBuffer.Count - $delimiter.Length, $delimiter.Length )            
            [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes( ($file.DirectoryName + '\' + $file.BaseName + $fileCounter + $file.Extension), $FileBuffer ) 
            [void]$fileBuffer.Clear()
            $fileCounter++
            $delimCounter1 = $delimCounter
        }
    }

    $byte = $fileReader.ReadByte()
}

if( $fileBuffer.Count -gt 0 ) {
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes( ($file.DirectoryName + '\' + $file.BaseName + $fileCounter + $file.Extension), $fileBuffer ) 
    [void]$fileBuffer.Clear()
}

[void]$fileReader.Close()
[void]$fileReader.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, getting a couple of recurring errors, examples:
`Cannot convert value "8220" to type "System.Byte". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte."`
and
`Exception calling "RemoveAt" with "1" argument(s): "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

Comment: Interesting, the script is running here without any Problems. Is it possible to provide your large file for download on a webserver (or part of it), e.g. zip-format?

Comment: I'll get something over to you when I'm off-grid later, just a 2 meg file.  Some files it works fine on.

Comment: @TJB I believe that is because the `System.IO.StreamReader` 's Read() and Peek() methods read `[Char]`'s, returned as Int32. The code is casting these as `[byte]`, but this way it can only handle ASCII and not UTF8. ( [char]8220 --> `“`)

Comment: @TJB Perhaps using a [System.IO.FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.read?view=netframework-4.8) could help, because that reads bytes

Comment: @Theo I've updated the script using System.IO.FileStream now, thanks for the hint

Comment: Wow, that was quick!

Comment: Improved, now script checks encoding of file first and encodes delimiter-string to the same Encoding.

Comment: Hi, sorry for radio silence, will check against the erroring files on Monday. Really appreciate the input.  I can confirm these files are UCS2-LE BOM/UTF16 so makes sense.

Comment: @f6a4 tested on an errorring file this morning. Currently script no longer errors, however the split doesn't appear to be functioning and sends everything to one file.

Comment: This means, that the encoding of the file is still not considered in the script. Could you provide me a small example for download of the original file? So I'm able to analyze the encoding and add the to switch-block in the script.

Comment: Please try here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SJV7TH8qW_2g0g4Ji1FuStsyUpYAedy6/view?usp=sharing

You will have to download, it's only 20 lines plus header but I tried it on the 5 delimiter split and it still did 1 file.

Comment: Thanks, this is a UTF16-LE encoding. I'll check and test in the office today.

Comment: utf-16 was missing, I've updated the script accordingly. Please try again.

Comment: @f6a4 thanks again - not quite getting the desired results my end, it produces as per the below zip:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LCHFloc5u0Fp--qDek5NGWj_GjPOQ9Gb
NB: I have amended the original file (same link) to provide an LF only split row at the request of iRon (comment in the original question).

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded your example again and checked with an online [hex-editor](https://hexed.it/), but I still can't find any `LF` (`00 0A`) that are *not* preceded with an `CR` (`00 0A`). It could be google drive but it might also be the application were you work with.
In other words: how do you check for `LF` and/or `CR`?

Anyways, as this unclear, I have created my own test file with `LF` (`` `n ``) and `CRLF` (default line ends):

```
$TestFile = '.\Test.csv'

$Csv = "Id|Text
2146079|Line 1
3449512|Line 2 `n Line 2a
3449783|Line 3
2146079|Line 4
3449512|Line 5 `n Line 5a
3449783|Line 6 `n Line 6a
2146079|Line 7
3449512|Line 8
3449783|Line 9"

$Csv | Out-File $TestFile # -Encoding Unicode
```

Although PowerShell is able to work with dotnet classes as [IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8) and [IO.FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.8), it has its own sophisticated streaming mechanism and native cmdlets to do so:

```
$FileFolder = [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($TestFile)
$FileName   = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($TestFile)
$FileExt    = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($TestFile)

$LinesPerFile = 3
$FileCount = 0
$LineCount = 0

Get-Content $TestFile -Delimiter "`r`n" | ForEach-Object {
    $NewFile = !($LineCount++ % $LinesPerFile)
    If ($NewFile) {$FileCount++}
    $Path = [IO.Path]::Combine($FileFolder, ("$FileName{0:D3}.csv" -f $FileCount))
    If ($NewFile) {Set-Content -Path $Path -Value $_}
    Else          {Add-Content -Path $Path -Value $_}
}
```

Comment: Functionally this works.  However, the files as noted in the original question are large and this approach is slow (and much slower, I think, than .Net). Kudos for the correct logic, however.

Comment: Yes, you might be right. At the other hand, when the PowerShell pipeline is correctly used, each row lines is immediately unloaded from memory and passed to the output file which might result in a performance advantage (especially with slower/remote input and/or output) but that completly depends on the actual used case.